# Redirecionamento 301 - Plataforma Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Utilizo a Platforma do Google Cloud App Engine para Hospedar Site Estático e Estou tendo problemas em fazer o *Redirect 301* da versão `WWW` para `NOUN-WWW` e também da versão `Http` para `Https`.

O Servidor é o Google FrontEnd
Esse é o Domínio Principal - https://presencadigital.co

Gostaria de que as versões abaixo fossem redirecionadas para o Dóminio Principal
https://www.presencadigital.co
http://www.presencadigital.co
http://presencadigital.co

O Arquivo que utilizo para fazer o Deploy é o APP.yaml, através da Interface Gcloud.

App.yaml

```
runtime: php55 
api_version: 2.3

handlers:
   url: /
   static_files: index.html
   upload: index.html
   expiration: 0s
   http_headers:
     Link:  <assets/img/logoWebPresencaDigitalTransparent.png>; rel=preload; as=image
```

Pesquisei sobre o Redirecionamento e oque utilizam é o arquivo HTAccess, para Servidores APACHE, não sei como implementar através do app.yaml.

---

### Atualização

Seguindo o dica do  @dhauptman coloquei a tag "secure:always" em cada declaração de upload do app.yaml e resolveu o problema do http -> https

```
handlers:
   url: /
   static_files: index.html
   upload: index.html
   secure: always
   expiration: 0s
```

Problema agora é como utilizar o redirect_http_response_code: 301 para apontar o domínio www.presencadigital.co -> presencadigital.co

Comment: Qual problema exatamente você esta tendo? Recomendo seguir as instruções deste [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains).

Comment: O Mapeamento do Domínio já funciona, o problema é quando Utilizo por exemplo o endereço com http, gostaria que o Servidor fizesse o redirecionamento para o endereço https. Atualizei agora mesmo a problemática da questão!

Comment: Para redirecionar de http para https inclua `secure: always` e `redirect_http_response_code: 301` no elemento `handlers`. Mais informações [aqui](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#handlers_element).

Comment: secure:always funcionou, muito obrigado!
o redirect_http_response_code:31 não consegui implementar ;(